# Pending Intent doesn´t work, nothing happens

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I used this source: https://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/android-complete-widget-tutorial-including-source-code/

After I go through the tutorial, the intent doesn´t work. Nothing happens.
Some of my code:

```
public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.companyname.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

On an other java file:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("com.companyname.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE")){
        updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(context);
    }
}
```

Here call the buildButtonPendingIntent:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int[] appWidgetIds) {

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

    pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);
}
```

Manifest file: (some parts)

```
    <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action
                android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="MyWidgetIntentReceiver"
        android:label="widgetBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.companyname.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: where is the code who call buildButtonPendingIntent()?

Comment: I just edited the post

Comment: Post your manifest that start with <receiver>

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: try to log intent.getAction() onReceive, to make sure is it received or not

Comment: Your manifest looks a bit strange. Normally the `android:name` for components like `<activity>` or `<receiver>` starts with a dot, like `android:name=".MyWidgetIntentReceiver"`. The name must be a class name and it needs to either be fully-qualified (like `"my.company.com.MyWidgetIntentReceiver"` or, if it begins with a dot, the package name set in the manifest is preprended to fully qualify the class name. Does any of your code work?